# Constructor of a children class that have an array that contains objects of another class

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, constructor, composition

Dialog.h

```
#include "WBasic.h"
#include "WButton.h"
#include "WData.h"

#ifndef WDIALOG_H_INCLUDED
#define WDIALOG_H_INCLUDED


class WDialog : public WBasic
{

    private:
    WButton wB;
    WData wD;


    public:
    //Constructor
    WDialog(const int& e = 0, const WButton& = WButton(0,0), const WData& = WData(0,0,0));

    ~WDialog();

};


#endif // WDIALOG_H_INCLUDED
```

Dialog.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WDialog.h"


WDialog::WDialog(const int& e, const WButton& WBUTTON, const WData& WDATA) :
WBasic(e), wB(WBUTTON), wD(WDATA)
{
}
```

The code above works great, however I'm trying to make "WButton wB" a vector changing it to"WButton wB[3];"

```
class WDialog : public WBasic
{

    private:
    WButton wB[3];
    WData wD;

};
```

But then I've no idea how deal with the Constructor.

Comment: Then you have to pass an array of buttons. Why don't you use a `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vector to solve this problem.
I have written a small example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

    class A{

    };
    class B{
        public:
            B():vec (4,A())
            {
            }
        private :
            vector<A> vec;
    };
    int main() {
        // your code goes here
        B obj();

        return 0;
    }
```

You can observe how I have initialized vector vec with three class A object.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if you can (your compiler support C++11) prefer std::array

```
#include <array>

std::array<WButton, 3> wB;
```

Then in your contructor use an initializer list:

```
WBasic(e),
wB{WButton(...), WButton(...), WButton(...)},
wD(WDATA)
```